# Callgrind does not see source in dynamically loaded SO

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, valgrind, callgrind

I'm attempting to run KCacheGrind on some results of callgrind.  Basically the codebase is a plugin container that launches a shared object to run a specific function.  Upon using Callgrind to profile this application, I can see the costs at the function level, but not at the source level.

I can see at the source level with the plugin container code, before it launches the SO, but I can't see any code contained in the SO that was launched.

I know I'm compiling with debug symbols on, but for some reason I am unable to see the dynamically loaded SO source code.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a minimal example (two source files, `main` plus one function, one shared lib, one executable)? What happens if you do Settings/Configure KCacheGrind/Annotations and add your source base explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this problem too.  The way to fix it is to stop the host application from unloading the plugins before it exits.  In my case I was trying to profile C modules for Lua and Lua was unloading the modules when the VM exited normally.  To fix this issues I had the script call os.exit() to do a forced shutdown.

Either disable plugin unloading in the plugin container, or create a plugin the allows you to force the application to exit (calling _exit(0)).

Comment: would killing the plugin container work as well?  such as doing a `ps -ef | grep <plugin_container>` and then killing the pid associated with it?  Instead of the usual SIGTERM Ctrl-D?

Comment: I ended up removing the dlclose call to the SO and it worked!